# Dealing with Simulink libraries

Tags: simulink

I have a - maybe very simple - problem:

I created my own library and dragged my custom blocks into a new model.
After closing my library window my simulation didn't find any of those blocks, because it isn't opended as window.

How can I workaround this problem by adding a reference or something similar?

Greets, poeschlorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PreLoadFcn callback of the model to load the library (load_system).

Comment: can you please tell me, how to add this function into my model? I'm a little bit confiused by the mathworks documentary

Comment: It's the second tab of "Model Properties" (menu Files of your model). Simply add "load_system( your lib )" in the first callback.

Comment: In which format must the "your lib" appear? e.g. "C:\simulink\lib\mylib.mdl"?

Comment: Yes, an absolute or relative path (with single quotes). Relative is better.
You can add a path to the variable PATH with `addpath`. The most elegant way to d it is probably to set it in your initialization file (relatively to the directory of init).

Answer (score 1):

The library doesn't have to be open when you start the simulation, Simulink will automatically resolve the library link and load the library when necessary.  But, the library has to be on your MATLAB path after you save it.  Make sure that the directory where you saved the library is on your path.

Comment: this requires to set the path on every new computer I am working with...is there a "dynamic" way to solve this a little bit more elegantly?